# Log value to file

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c# development.

I have inherited code that for me is complicated and not well commented.

There is one thing I need help on.

1) I am passing a file handle in to the below function and what I want to be able to do is log the value returned from 'e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.Enterprise.ToString()' - I guessing I can re-write the function but not to alter logic/purpose of the function - how do I do this?

```
public static IObservable<GenericTrapMessage> ToObservableGenericTrapMessage(this TrapV2MessageHandler handler, Logger Logger,  Func<Variable,  KeyValuePair<string, object>> variableMapping)
        {

            Logger.Log("ToObservableGenericTrapMessage V2", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information);

            return Observable.FromEventPattern<TrapV2MessageReceivedEventArgs>(
                    h => handler.MessageReceived += h,
                    h => handler.MessageReceived -= h)
                .Select(e => new GenericTrapMessage
                {
                    Timestamp = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.TimeStamp,
                    Sender = e.EventArgs.Sender.ToString() + ":" + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString(),
                    Type = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.Enterprise.ToString(),
                    Variables = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.Variables().Select(variableMapping).ToList()

                });

        }
```

Comment: maybe you can extract the value from inputs? Is it present in TrapV2MessageHandler ?

Comment: Is `IObservable<T>.Select` lazy (sorry, don't know RX)? If yes and you don't want to change behavior, then better add logging where caller is using returned value. If not, then you can extend `Select` lambda parameter to a multiline where you create instance of `new GenericTrapMessage`, log its `Type` and return instance.

Comment: The problem I have with TrapV2MessageHandler is there are lots and lots properties/methods and I had a look through them but there's nothing obvious...

Comment: @Sinatr - you wrote...."If not, then you can extend Select lambda parameter to a multiline where you create instance of new GenericTrapMessage, log its Type and return instance." - can you give me a idea how to do this?

Comment: @IanCarrick [Tau's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883667/1997232) below is what I mean. I don't know RX, so can't say for sure if this approach is ok or a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, the `Select` is performed using an expression lambda; you could simply make it a statement lambda and perform a log in there:

```cs
//...
return Observable.FromEventPattern<TrapV2MessageReceivedEventArgs>(
        h => handler.MessageReceived += h,
        h => handler.MessageReceived -= h)
    .Select(e => {
            Logger.Log(e.EventArgs.Sender.ToString());
            return new GenericTrapMessage {
                    Timestamp = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.TimeStamp,
                    Sender = e.EventArgs.Sender.ToString() + ":" + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString(),
                    Type = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.Enterprise.ToString(),
                    Variables = e.EventArgs.TrapV2Message.Variables().Select(variableMapping).ToList()

                };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks this answer was perfect and resolved my issue.